# Linkedin API response in IPhone

Tags: api, iphone-sdk-3.0, linkedin-api

As API response of Linkedin API comes into function

```
- (void)linkedInEngine:(RDLinkedInEngine *)engine requestSucceeded:(RDLinkedInConnectionID *)identifier withResults:(id)results {
```

How we recognize that coming result is for which API

**Amit Battan**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in this way..

Every request return `RDLinkedInConnectionID` object
and in delegate method corresponding `(RDLinkedInConnectionID *)identifier` object here

I have taken a Dictionary for managing it

**Code on request**

```
[connectionDict setObject:@"afterlogin" forKey:[controller.engine profileForCurrentUser]];
```

**Code on response in *delegate method***

```
if ( [[connectionDict objectForKey:identifier] isEqualToString:@"afterlogin"] ) {
    //Your Code
}
```